# How to fix The provider provider.aws does not support data source

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-security-group

I am trying to get the `id` of the `default` security group created when creating a vpc using `terraform`.

Here's what I tried:

```
data "aws_default_security_group" "default" {
  vpc_id = module.ecs_vpc.vpc_id
}
```

but I am getting this error:

> The provider provider.aws does not support data source
> "aws_default_security_group"

can someone help me on this?

Comment: How did it go with the issue? The problem still persists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get default security group you just use `aws_security_group`:

```
data "aws_security_group" "default" {
  name = "default"
  vpc_id = module.ecs_vpc.vpc_id
}
```

Alternatively, you want to manage default group using TF, you can get it using (not `data`):

```
resource "aws_default_security_group" "default" {
  vpc_id = data.aws_vpc.default.id
}
```

``